# How to remove django_social_auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I want to switch to django_allauth from django_social_auth. I ran:

```
pip uninstall django_social_auth
```

and this completed successfully. However I can no longer run syncdb because of the error:

```
ImportError: No module named social_auth
```

Comment: did you remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances are Django is still looking for the `social_auth` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Please remove this and see if it continues to happen.

You'll also need to make sure you remove all references to `social_auth` including your `urls.py` file.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Make sure you do the reverse of the [setup documentation](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#application-setup)